# SQL automatically ignore or delete duplicate column when creating new table

Tags: sql

I want to create a new table from an SQL query however I keep getting

> #1060 - Duplicate column name `idvisit`

The query works but I keep getting an error when I try to create a table

```
CREATE TABLE marketin_testDatabase.results AS
SELECT *
    FROM marketin_yolopiwik.matomo_log_link_visit_action
    LEFT OUTER JOIN marketin_yolopiwik.matomo_log_visit
    ON marketin_yolopiwik.matomo_log_visit.idvisit = 
        marketin_yolopiwik.matomo_log_link_visit_action.idvisit;
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have common column names in both of tables. So, alias tables and Instead of asterisk, individually write all column names :

```
CREATE TABLE marketin_testDatabase.results AS
  SELECT a.idvisit, a.col1, a.col2 ....,
                    v.col1, v.col2 .... 
    FROM marketin_yolopiwik.matomo_log_link_visit_action a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN marketin_yolopiwik.matomo_log_visit v
    ON ( v.idvisit = a.idvisit );
```

If Only common column name is `idvisit`, then the following may be used with asterisk :

```
CREATE TABLE marketin_testDatabase.results AS
  SELECT a.*,
         v.col1, v.col2 .... -- all columns of "matomo_log_visit" except idvisit
    FROM marketin_yolopiwik.matomo_log_link_visit_action a
    LEFT OUTER JOIN marketin_yolopiwik.matomo_log_visit v
    ON ( v.idvisit = a.idvisit );
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it obvious?  Both tables have a column called `idvisit`.  If this is the only duplicate column name, you can use:

```
CREATE TABLE marketin_testDatabase.results AS
    SELECT *
    FROM marketin_yolopiwik.matomo_log_link_visit_action lva LEFT JOIN
         marketin_yolopiwik.matomo_log_visit lv
         USING (idvisit);
```

However, it is better to explicitly list the columns.  One shortcut is to take the columns from the wider table and just list the rest from the other:

```
CREATE TABLE marketin_testDatabase.results AS
    SELECT lva.*, lv.?, lv.?, . . .
    FROM marketin_yolopiwik.matomo_log_link_visit_action lva LEFT JOIN
         marketin_yolopiwik.matomo_log_visit lv
         USING (idvisit);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no option in MySQL to ignore duplicate columns in a CREATE TABLE statement.

You should avoid using `SELECT *`. In this case, it gives duplicate column names because you join tables that contain columns of the same name.

You will have to write out the list of columns you want to keep, instead of using `SELECT *`. There is no query syntax for "select * except for a few."